# Mdframed box — why is it cropped?

Tags: mdframed

The first box box on the top (see the image below) is cropped and I don't know why:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
outside of the 


\global\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{%
linecolor=red,middlelinewidth=3pt,%
leftmargin=1cm,rightmargin=1cm
}
\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault,roundcorner=5]
Example Text
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault,roundcorner=5]
Example Text
\end{mdframed}

boxes.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The box isn't cropped when I compile. It could be an issue with your pdf viewer. Try zooming in or out on your pdf viewer (or try a different one) to see if it is truly cropped.

Comment: unrelated, but  `\global` can not be doing anything useful before `\mdfdefinestyle`

Comment: The problem manifests with XeLaTex.  It doesn't occur with pdfLaTex.  The problem isn't the viewer, but @Dan's comment let me to try pdfLaTex.

Comment: @DougRansom I don't get a crop with XeLaTeX (or pdfLaTeX).

Comment: I see disappearing lines in adobe reader and it is imho a zoom/viewer problem.  Try with tcolorbox instead.

Comment: It is purely on viewer problem, better to view the PDF output in `100%`, not in `fit to page` view

Answer (score 0):

Like some comments it is a problem of compiler preview. If you compile (pdflatex) and use an external pdf viewer you have the correct result:

[image]